# (AltoRouter) .htaccess file leads to 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, routes

First, I have to say I'm no htaccess expert but: I don't think my issue is about the routing library (AltoRouter) I use. I assume it's a pure htaccess problem since everything works local.

However I'm using [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/) to implement routes for my website. I have a `.htaccess`-file with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I developed my website for some months now and I'm ready to publish it, so I never had problems on my localhost.

But uploading the same `.htaccess`-file is causing troubles on my remote host.

**I noticed this behaviour:**

- If I'm at my root directory, e.g. `www.domainA.com`, everything works fine
- As soon as I click on a link on my website like `www.domainA.com/signup/` the loading indicator in my browser spins forever (like **30minutes**!)
- The same index page is displayed all the time, nothing new loads

So for this long time I can't do *anything*, even if I delete the `.htaccess`-file from the remote server and refresh the page. I have to wait like 30minutes until the page responds again with a

> 505 Internal Error

page.

**If my problem is about AltoRouter**, I can only assume it is the option setting the base path:

```
$router->setBasePath('/projectA');
```

But since my folder names are the same both on localhost and on my remote web root, I don't know if the problem is there.

__

Sidenote: My web root is organized like the following structure. I seperated each folder by domain.

`[domainA]`

`[domainB]`

`[domainC]`

So it's similiar to my local structure. If I call `localhost/domainA` in my browser it's `C:\xampp\htdocs\domainA`.

PS: My provider just told me that there are no log files I can check. I have to check htaccess errors for myself.

Comment: I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^fake-user$` to check if this works as user agent named `fake-user` and it does! But when switching to an other user, the same errors occur and my whole domains in my web root are down again. Then I delete this htaccess file and it takes some time again until all domains are up again. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe it, but it's about setting the base path. After hours I just found out that this line `$router->setBasePath('');` on my remote host is causing all the problems. You don't have to use this function when you're in the root directory, then it works like on the localhost. Maybe this helps other users when they're confused why it isn't working on the remote host but on the localhost.

Comment: Hi, 
i just have the basically same problem, I described it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158155/altorouter-not-doing-the-routing-correctly

Do you have any idea about the problem? I tried removing the line with `$router->setBasePath('');`, but still the same result...